# collect dictionairy values in python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collect

I have a list which has dict values in it. I want to group by ts and collect other values. Please note that ts is common and will be there in all dictionaries in the list. But the other values like HP, BP can change in each dictionary. 
Please suggest.

input

```
[
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:01', u'HP': 1}, 
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:01', u'BP': 1}, 
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:01', u'AP': 1}, 
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:02', u'HP': 1},
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:02', u'AP': 1}
]
```

output

```
[
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:01', u'HP': 1, u'BP': 1,u'AP': 1  }, 
{'ts': '2016-11-29 19:02', u'HP': 1, u'AP': 1} 
]
```

Comment: What if there are more than one `HP` corresponding to a `ts`?

Comment: Is the condition "collate dictionary if it contains `ts` as a key"?

Comment: I dont want  to give -1 but as @KlausD. said what did you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for _, v in groupby(a,lambda x:x['ts']):
    temp_dict = {}
    for dic in v:
        temp_dict.update(dic)
    result.append(temp_dict)

print result
```

Output:

```
[
 {u'AP': 1, u'HP': 1, u'BP': 1, 'ts': '2016-11-29 19:01'}, 
 {u'AP': 1, u'HP': 1, 'ts': '2016-11-29 19:02'}
]
```

Comment: Kool, thanks Ahsanul, Works fine